# Printing multi keyed Hash in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl hash that I am indexing like this:

```
my %hash;
$hash{'number'}{'even'} = [24, 44, 38, 36];
$hash{'number'}{'odd'} = [23, 43, 37, 35];
```

When I try to print key names like this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash{'number'})
{
   print "Key: $key\n";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not hash slice) at test.pl
```

However when I pass the array ref to a function and print it there, it prints the values:

```
test(\%hash);

sub test
{
   my ($hash) = @_;
   foreach my $key (keys %{$hash->{'number'}})
   {
       print "Key: $key\n";     #outputs: even odd
   }
}
```

Can someone please let me know what is going wrong here? Also if I have multi-keyed hash which I have in this case where hash is indexed by both 'number' and 'even' or 'odd' if I do  something like this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash)
{
print "First Key: $key\n";  #Outputs number
}
```

Then will I always get 'number' as the output right and I can never get 'even', 'odd' as outputs, correct? This is just to know good coding practice :)

This is the full code:

```
sub test
{
    my ($hash) = @_;
    foreach my $key (keys %{$hash->{'number'}})
    {
        print "Key: $key\n";
    }

}

my %hash;
$hash{'number'}{'even'} = [24, 44, 38, 36];
$hash{'number'}{'odd'} = [23, 43, 37, 35];

test(\%hash);

foreach my $key (keys %hash)
{
    print "First Key: $key\n";
}

foreach my $key (keys %hash{'number'})
{
  print "Key: $key\n";
}
```

Thanks,
Newbie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my %hash;
$hash{'number'}{'even'} = [24, 44, 38, 36];
$hash{'number'}{'odd'} = [23, 43, 37, 35];
```

`%hash` is a hash whose keys are strings (`'number'`), and whose values are hash references.

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash{'number'})
{
   print "Key: $key\n";
}
```

To refer to a value that's part of `%hash`, you want to write `$hash{'number'}`, not `%hash{'number'}`.

But `$hash{'number'}` is a hash reference, not a hash.  To refer to the hash that it refers to, you can write this:

```
%{$hash{'number'}}
```

Putting it all together this:

```
my %hash;
$hash{'number'}{'even'} = [24, 44, 38, 36];
$hash{'number'}{'odd'} = [23, 43, 37, 35];

foreach my $key (keys %{$hash{'number'}}) {
   print "Key: $key\n";
}
```

will produce this output:

```
Key: even
Key: odd
```

(possibly not in that order).

Comment: And, for academic interest, here is more information on hash slices, which what the original code was accidentally doing: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices

Comment: OMG...it was like that! I was thinking that the whole name was a key! Thanks for the detailed explanation. It really helped :)

Comment: And if you are using 5.14 or later, keys, values, each, push, pop, slice, shift and unshift can now function on references. That means `keys %{ $hash{k} }` can be rewritten as `keys $hash{k}`.  Rejoice!

Comment: @kbenson: And I'll be glad to use that as soon as I'm guaranteed that my code doesn't need to run on anything older than 5.14.  *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
$hash{'number'}{'even'} = [24, 44, 38, 36];
$hash{'number'}{'odd'} = [23, 43, 37, 35];

foreach my $i(keys %hash){
    print $i;
    foreach my $j(keys %{$hash{$i}}){
        print "\t".$j."\t";
        print join(" ",@{$hash{'number'}{$j}})."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it worked! Thank you very much.  But what is the motivation of putting extra curly braces? I mean `keys %{$hash{'number'}} worked but `keys %hash{'number'}` did not, why is that?

Comment: Note the difference in your own examples - in the second one where you pass to the subroutine this is exactly what you are doing.  In the first one you are not.  Without the extra braces it's not actually a hash.